# How to access my array of objects that I created with my constructor in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I am still very new to learning Angular and I do not fully understand everything yet so please bear with me. I created an array of objects that contains all the data I need and am trying to display the data using the ngFor directive. I know the data is there because I console logged it out but I do not know how to access the data using my ngFor loop.

This is the data that is console logged, console.log(this.forecastData);

```
[HighLows]
0: HighLows {days: Array(6), highs: Array(6), lows: Array(6)}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Here is my html

```
<div *ngFor="let data of this.weather.forecastHiLoData">
  {{data.days}}
  {{data.highs}}
  {{data.lows}}
</div>
```

I've tried different scenarios that just give me errors like

```
<div *ngFor="let data of this.weather.forecastHiLoData[0]">
```

or

```
  {{data[0].days}}
```

Maybe it is the way I constructed the new object. When I console log out the HighLows array to the zeroth index, console.log(this.forecastData[0]), I get just this

```
HighLows {days: Array(6), highs: Array(6), lows: Array(6)}
days: (6) [1546225200000, 1546236000000, 1546322400000, 1546408800000, 1546495200000, 1546581600000]
highs: (6) [4.56, 13.95, 2.75, -0.24, 9.14, 13.93]
lows: (6) [4.56, 3.73, -1.44, -6.73, -8.73, -5.08]
__proto__: Object
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wtu3ym?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

**UPDATE**

Looks like I am getting erros in my terminal that I will have to look into which I did not realize until now. I am still learning how to use classes/interfaces and constructors.

```
ERROR in src/app/services/weather.service.ts(39,5): error TS2322: Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'HighLows'.
  Property 'days' is missing in type 'any[]'.
src/app/services/weather.service.ts(40,20): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Days[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'.
  Type 'Days' is not assignable to type 'number'.
src/app/services/weather.service.ts(150,32): error TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Days'.
```

Comment: Just add the code where you assign the array values - remove the `this` keyword from your html and try to access the array that might solve your solution

Comment: @rahul The reason I have the word **this** is because the data is being accessed in my service component.

Comment: Yeah but i don't think this will work for you in your html, in your component decorator if you add the html as a `templateUrl` then that html will be the part of your component - so all the properties will be accessed by the html without using **this**

Comment: @rahul Oh okay. You were right. I removed all the **this** keyword and everything else on my page still worked as normal. I did not realize you did not have to specify **this** when accessing a Dependency Injector. However, my data is still not being iterated through

Comment: Great - btw just show me your code where you assign the value for the `weather` and is there any error while looping ? Because you are looping the `weather` array which as some more arrays in it - you are not iterating it though

Comment: @rahul I think I just realized it cannot iterate through the data is because I have another array inside of the object. Let me update my post with the data I am assigning to weather.

Comment: @Rahul I think I misunderstood what you were asking me. I did not have any errors while looping but the data is not being displayed. I think I am just not accessing the array I need it to loop but I am not sure how that code should look. Did I provide you the info you were looking for?

Comment: please use http://stackblitz.com/. And set your test project on it, to easily see it.

Comment: @Yoarthur https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wtu3ym?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @Rahul It looks like I am getting errors in my terminal but not the console log. There is something wrong with the way I am setting my models. I need a break :\

Comment: First import the models folders. Second, Define the object you want to display in here https://jsoneditoronline.org/ (A mock). This will help me (and to you) to understand the type of data you want to display.

Comment: @Yoarthur The import models should already be imported. I put my info into the website. Not sure if it is saved however, Ive never used it before. https://jsoneditoronline.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen your Stackblitz and found some issue in your code - seems like you are trying to print a array `weather.forecastHiLoData` has multiple arrays inside it you need to loop through all the arrays to get the value

Try something like this

```
<div *ngFor="let day of weather.forecastHiLoData">
  <div *ngFor="let item of day.days">
    Days: {{item}}
  </div>
  <div *ngFor="let high of day.highs">
    Highs: {{high}}
  </div>
  <div *ngFor="let low of day.lows">
    Lows: {{low}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I can read all the values when i loop the array like above - whereas i have done some changes in your `interface` and `services`

**HighLow.ts**

```
import {Days} from './days';
import {Lows}from  './lows';
import {Highs}from './highs';

export class HighLows {
  days: Days[];
  highs:Highs[];
  lows: Lows[];

  constructor(days: Days[], highs: Highs[], lows: Lows[]) {
    this.days = days;
    this.highs = highs;
    this.lows = lows;
  }
}
```

**Weather.service.ts**

Your `forecastHiLoData` should be an array of `HighLows[]` and it should read as

`public forecastHiLoData: HighLows[];`

Finally I'm not sure that you can read your `private` variable on your `html` so make sure you have it as `public` - So your weather service injection should be public

`constructor(public weather: WeatherService) { }`

With all this changes i think you're done - Hope it works - Happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was trying to achieve. I did not know you can nest ngFor loops like this. Also, from an experienced developer's standpoint, overall how was the rest of my code? I am trying to get validation that I am on the right path so I can land me a job.

Comment: Yeah everything is good - but i feel your code is too tightly coupled - make sure you have your service to provide only data - logic should be available in your component is better - because the service you worte will serve only that component if you want to use in another component any changes might affect both - your code should be independent and single responsibility classes - finally make sure you have the correct data types for all properties typescript is all about that - some ideas from my side sorry if i ment anything wrong

Comment: Ok thanks! I think I understood everything you said except for making my code "independent and single responsibility classes". If I understand correctly, what you are saying is to separating the code into smaller pieces that are related to each other for easier maintenance and scalability correct?? (To my understanding this is basic idea of how to use Angular.)

Comment: Yeah - that is what i came to say :) happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

saw your stackblits code. unfortunately *ngFor works in a different way.

ts code.

```
items = [
 "a", "b", "c", "d"
]
```

html code.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor=”let item of items”>{{ item }}</li>
</ul>
```

In layman terms, you need to create a local variable above constructor, loop through it in HTML file to get what's inside it. (You can also create observables and subscribe them via async pipe but for the moment you can ignore it) Hope this helps